# Face Tracking and Virtual Reality

Tags: augmented-reality, face-recognition

I'm searching for a face tracking system to use in an augmented reality project. I'm trying to find an open source and multi-platform application for it. The goal is to return the direction where the face is looking to interact with the virtual environment, (something like [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jd3-eiid-Uw)).

I've downloaded the sources of the above Johnny Lee's application and tried to use [Free Track](http://www.free-track.net/english/) too, making my own headset (some kind of monster, hehe). But it's not good to be limited to infrared points in your head.

These days I've download FaceTrackNoIR, but when I launch the program I get ["No DLL was found in the Waterfall procedure."](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-integrated-performance-primitives-intel-ipp-error-no-dll-was-found/) that I'm actually trying to solve.

Anyone knows a good application, library, code, lecture, anything that could help me to find a good path for this?

Thank you all!

I'll try to post results someday :-)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android might be interesting for you. It is Java code so you can use OpenCV's Java interface. If you wan't to use C++, the code looks almost exactly the same

Answer (score 0):

I would take a look at [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/). It is a general purpose machine-learning and computer vision C++ library. One of the examples in the download is a real-time face tracker that connects to a video camera connected to your computer and draws squares around any faces in the camera view.

Comment: Yes, I'm doing another research using OpenCV and it's very cool! But I don't want to reinvent the wheel (yet).