# Android JavaCV facerecogniser - Fatal signal 11 when training faceRecogniser?

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition, javacv

So my project is to make a face recognition(not detection) app for Android. My plan is to use JavaCV with the contrib library facerecogniser. However when training the recogniser the app crashes with this error:

Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) 0xdeadbaad (code=1). the error logs can be found here:

[Error Logs](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/18ooMFc46DdTKetgM-jRJHte-eFJPMIACt2O86aIG18g/edit)

The code I'm using to do this is as follows:

```
 MatVector images;
 CvArr labelsCV;

 final int numberOfImages = 20;
 File faceDir = new File("/sdcard/FaceDB");

 images = new MatVector(numberOfImages);

 ArrayList<Integer> labels = new ArrayList<Integer>();
 IntPointer iPoint = new IntPointer();

 CvArr image;
 // Load an image:
 image = cvLoadImage(faceDir + "/s1/1.pgm");
 // And put it into the MatVector:
 images.put(0, image); 
 // and put the label in
 labels.add(0);

  for (Integer i: labels){
         iPoint.put(i);
  }

  labelsCV = new CvArr(iPoint);

  FaceRecognizerPtr model = createFisherFaceRecognizer(0,1000);
  // Then train it. See how I call get(), to get the FaceRecognizer inside the FaceRecognizerPtr:
  model.get().train(images, labelsCV);
```

I'm not sure but it could be something to do with my labelsCV variable and pointer, I'm not really sure how to do this.

Any help would be much apreciated thanks

Comment: There is working code available here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android

Comment: the above working code fails in android because of memory reference