# How can I find implement of class FaceRecognizer in javacv?

Tags: opencv, javacv

I have read source code javaCV, file opencv_contrib.java with class FaceRecognizer. But it is just a prototype, can I find implement of this class anywhere?

Comment: Answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android

Answer (score 0):

You need to call one of the static methods that create recognizers:

```
FaceRecognizer eigenRecog =   com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createEigenFaceRecognizer();
FaceRecognizer fischerRecog = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createFisherFaceRecognizer();
FaceRecognizer lbphRecog =    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createLBPHFaceRecognizer();
```