# Face recognition using OpenCV in android?

Tags: android, opencv, face-recognition

I am able to detect faces using open cv but I don't know how to process face recognition.

I googled a lot but I didn't find any articles or blogs that can guide me.

Can someone help me to develop face recognition App in android?

Comment: link is not working..

Comment: @Mohamed_AbdAllah link was broken

Answer (score 11):

You can always use JavaCV that is a kind of wrapper for the native OpenCV functions:

See:
[Face Recognition on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android)

In order to get everything working you have to extract some `.so` files to your `libs` folder in the project:

Follow the instructions on [this page](http://blog.drndos.sk/2013/04/how-to-run-javacv-with-sample-face-recognition-on-android-arm-device-netbeans-and-nbandroid/)

> 1. Go to File > New > Folder, select your project as parent folder, type "libs/armeabi" as Folder name, and click Finish.
> 2. Copy javacpp.jar and javacv.jar into the newly created "libs" folder.
> 3. Extract all the *.so files from javacv-android-arm.jar, opencv-2.4.6.1-android-arm.jar, and ffmpeg-2.0.1-android-arm.jar directly into the newly created "libs/armeabi" folder, without creating any of the subdirectories found in the JAR files.
> 4. Navigate to Project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries and click "Add JARs...".
> 5. select both javacpp.jar and javacv.jar from the newly created "libs" folder.

*Source: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/*

Include `javacpp` and `javacv` in your `libs` folder: https://code.google.com/p/javacv/

Find the required jars in `javacpp` after download and extract the required SO files (yes, you can open the jar with WinRAR)

Compile and build the code experimented in: [Face Recognition on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android)

And here you go! It worked for me, so I'm sure it will work for you!

Comment: @Telmo: can you have any sample apk or sample code so that we can know where I am lacking. I am searching for face recognition for a long time

Answer (score 2):

In Library OpenCV.vers. for Android go to folder "samples". Sample Face-Detection for you=)

Comment: Face detection and face recognition are different things ;) Face detection tells you where is the face and face recognition tells you who's the owner of the face.