# Developing Face Recognition App

Tags: android, face-detection

i'm new to developing android apps in general.
I'm trying to create an application that given a certain image it would detect faces and would give me the eye locations and other info.

I've done some research and i found some stuff such as, the android FaceDetector API and OpenCV.

Could anyone give me some advice on how to make an app like this or send me a link with any info related to this, all help would be great!

Thanks, Daniel.

Comment: You can use this https://github.com/darwinfrancis/viola library to get cropped faces from bitmap image

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have worked with Face recognition for a while.
If you want to use OpenCV you could do a better effort searching in SO and you can found things like this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18922603/1332549).

The best one for me is the SDK provide by lockheed martin... but it's too expensive :S for a single person.

**Edited**
"Face detection and face recognition are different things ;) Face detection tells you where is the face and face recognition tells you who's the owner of the face"

If you choose OpenCV, you can find full doc in [official page](http://docs.opencv.org/platforms/android/service/doc/index.html).
I'm going to give you a overview :

You can use OpenCV in your app using "OpenCV Manager" or with "Static Initialization on OpenCV Android".

About the first one:

> OpenCV Manager is an Android service targeted to manage OpenCV library binaries on end users devices. It allows sharing the OpenCV dynamic libraries between applications on the same device. The Manager provides the following benefits:
>
> 1. Less memory usage. All apps use the same binaries from service and do not keep native libs inside themselves;
> 2. Hardware specific optimizations for all supported platforms;
> 3. Trusted OpenCV library source. All packages with OpenCV are published on Google Play market;
> 4. Regular updates and bug fixes;

[image: usage model for end users]

About the second one:
A [complete tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/android_binary_package/dev_with_OCV_on_Android.html#) using eclipse.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @RyanHaining you are right, but because its not clear what "programming problem" he has, the answer to fit what he is asking is not clear (He got -4 probably because SO not works like a forum)

Comment: such resources are best provided in comments, they are helpful, but don't constitute their own answers

Comment: You are right again, Im going to add some of link stuff in answer

Answer (score 1):

You might try the new Android face API.  See the tutorial here about how to detect faces and facial landmarks:

https://developers.google.com/vision/detect-faces-tutorial

Answer (score 1):

I explain how to do it in [this article](https://medium.com/@estebanuri/real-time-face-recognition-with-android-tensorflow-lite-14e9c6cc53a5). I used a TensorFlow Lite with a  [MobileFaceNet](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1804.07573.pdf) implementation, achieving very accurate results and with surprisingly high speed.

You'll find the **source code** and an **APK** in [this repo](https://github.com/estebanuri/face_recognition)

[image]