# Android OpenCv Face recognition

Tags: opencv, face-recognition

I am stuck in recognizing face please help me out,below is my code

```
FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_contrib.createFisherFaceRecognizer();
```

My Train method

```
 public void train(){

        IplImage img;
        IplImage grayImg;

        if(nameList!=null && nameList.size()>0){
            for (int i = 0; i < nameList.size(); i++) {
                String p = mPath+"person0/"+i+".png";
                img = cvLoadImage(p);
                labels[i] = i;
                grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                images.put(i, grayImg);
            }
        }
        faceRecognizer.train(images,labels);
    }
```

My Predict Method

```
public void predict(){
        String testPath = mPath+"test/person1.png";

        Mat img = imread(testPath);
        IplImage ipl = MatToIplImage(img,img.width(), img.width());
  int predicted = faceRecognizer.predict(ipl);
        Log.v(TAG," predicted : "+predicted);
    }
```

for checking purpose I am using sample image without using device camera,my  problem is the predict method gives same result for all sample,please guide me where am i doing mistake

Comment: Hi @Pratik Vyas, I'm new to this face recognition can you please guide me how to used openCV in Android. My Email: inzi769@gmail.com

Comment: @InzimamTariqIT : learn how to provide NDK support to andoird apps , and do some R&D on Opencv face recognize algorithms , then you will get idea on how to start with.

Comment: I have no knowledge of C, C++. Is there a strong knowledge require or with somewhat I can work?

Comment: you should have fundamentals knowledge, as understanding algorithms require basics understanding , so have patience and try learning  c++ and then move ahead

Answer (score 2):

After examining your code, I see a problem in how you collect labels. In this `labels[i] = i;` statement, you are setting one different label for each image you read. I think you have multiple images per person. Labels are numeric values (think of them like a code) assigned to each **PERSON** and not each **IMAGE**. If you had two persons with each having 3 images, label should be having values [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1].

Another possible problem you should check is that all images **MUST** be of the **SAME** size. This means every image you are reading in the loop must have same size **AND** also images used in `predict` must have same size. A good way to do that is by defining a fixed size, then resize every image you read to that fixed one.

Last problem I can think of is to use grayscale images only. Train method doesn't use color images. So same as image size, as soon as you read image, convert it to grayscale.

Further you can look at [Face Recognition on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android) and [Face recognition using OpenCV in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187084/face-recognition-using-opencv-in-android?rq=1)

Comment: thanks for the attention, i will look about it and response to you