# The method createFisherFaceRecognizer(int, double) in the type opencv_contrib is not applicable for the arguments ()

Tags: java, image, opencv, image-processing, face-recognition

I am trying to create demo like [Answer By Bytefish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android) But it produce the error. How can I resolve this problem?. Here is my code which i am trying. Any help would be really appreciated.

```
String trainingDir = "D:\\train";
                Mat testImage = Highgui.imread("D:\\photo.jpg",Highgui.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

                File root = new File(trainingDir);

                FilenameFilter pngFilter = new FilenameFilter() {
                  public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
                    return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
                  }
                };

                File[] imageFiles = root.listFiles(pngFilter);
                MatVector images = new MatVector(imageFiles.length);
                int[] labels = new int[imageFiles.length];
                int counter = 0;
                int label;
                IplImage img;
                IplImage grayImg;

                for (File image1 : imageFiles) {
                  img=cvLoadImage(image1.getAbsolutePath());
                  label = Integer.parseInt(image1.getName().split("\\-")[0]);
                  grayImg = IplImage.create(img.width(), img.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
                  cvCvtColor(img, grayImg, CV_BGR2GRAY);
                   images.put(counter,img);
                  labels[counter] = label;
                  counter++;
                }

                FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createFisherFaceRecognizer();
                 //FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createEigenFaceRecognizer();
                // FaceRecognizer faceRecognizer = createLBPHFaceRecognizer()

                faceRecognizer.train(images, labels);

                // Load the test image:
                Mat greyTestImage = new Mat(testImage.width(), testImage.height(), IPL_DEPTH_8U);
                Imgproc.cvtColor(testImage, greyTestImage, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

                // And get a prediction:
                int predictedLabel = faceRecognizer.predict(greyTestImage);
                System.out.println("Predicted label: " + predictedLabel);
```