# image comparison in Android by OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv

I have devised some code for image comparison. The matching part is still a bit flawed and I would love some assitance. The project can be found at - [Github](https://github.com/torcellite/imageComparator) .

I have these two images img1 and img2 .

[image] [image]

These are the images of same person . When I want to compare these two images , the following code returns false .

```
bmpimg1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpimg1, 100, 100, true);
                    bmpimg2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmpimg2, 100, 100, true);
                    Mat img1 = new Mat();
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg1, img1);
                    Mat img2 = new Mat();
                    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmpimg2, img2);
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(img1, img1, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 
                    Imgproc.cvtColor(img2, img2, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY); 
                    img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
                    img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
                    //Log.d("ImageComparator", "img1:"+img1.rows()+"x"+img1.cols()+" img2:"+img2.rows()+"x"+img2.cols());
                    Mat hist1 = new Mat();
                    Mat hist2 = new Mat();
                    MatOfInt histSize = new MatOfInt(180);
                    MatOfInt channels = new MatOfInt(0);
                    ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes1= new ArrayList<Mat>();
                    ArrayList<Mat> bgr_planes2= new ArrayList<Mat>();
                    Core.split(img1, bgr_planes1);
                    Core.split(img2, bgr_planes2);
                    MatOfFloat histRanges = new MatOfFloat (0f, 180f);              
                    boolean accumulate = false;
                    Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes1, channels, new Mat(), hist1, histSize, histRanges, accumulate);
                    Core.normalize(hist1, hist1, 0, hist1.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
                    Imgproc.calcHist(bgr_planes2, channels, new Mat(), hist2, histSize, histRanges, accumulate);
                    Core.normalize(hist2, hist2, 0, hist2.rows(), Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());
                        img1.convertTo(img1, CvType.CV_32F);
                        img2.convertTo(img2, CvType.CV_32F);
                        hist1.convertTo(hist1, CvType.CV_32F);
                        hist2.convertTo(hist2, CvType.CV_32F);

                        double compare = Imgproc.compareHist(hist1, hist2, Imgproc.CV_COMP_CHISQR);
                        Log.d("ImageComparator", "compare: "+compare);
                        if(compare>0 && compare<1500) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images may be possible duplicates, verifying", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            new asyncTask(MainActivity.this).execute();
                        }
                        else if(compare==0)
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images are exact duplicates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        else
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Images are not duplicates", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

How can I change my code so that on compare these two images , it returns true ? Any advice is of great help .

Answer (score 0):

You seem to only be comparing limited [feature vectors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_%28machine_learning%29), which in this case is only a histogram of the image. 
The algorithm you have used is not suitable for facial recognition as it only identifies on the image color spectrum.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android) possible duplicate on how to perform facial recognition.