# AR Core: Snapchat like face filtering

Tags: augmented-reality, arcore

Using AR Core I want to do Snapchat-like face filtering and AR. Is there a sample app with source code I can look at as a reference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of writing, ARCore is not suitable for face tracking and filtering. You can use [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/platforms/android/) and their [Face Recongition API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11699744/face-recognition-on-android).

For landmark detection, there is the [Facial Landmark API](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d47/tutorial_table_of_content_facemark.html) available for which you also can find a non-official [demo app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.enoxsoftware.facetrackerexample&hl=en_US) on Google play.

Comment: Do they have a sample for this ? Are there other free SDKs that offer it?

Comment: The linked StackOverflow question has a quite extensive example. Haven't tried it, though.

Comment: I don't think it's the same as the question. They answer about real time face detection, but the question is more than this. It's also required to "fit the mask" nicely on the face that was detected. Plus it's about 5 years ago, and I don't think it was available back then...

Comment: You are right. For this, you can use OpenCV's Facial Landmark API: https://docs.opencv.org/master/d5/d47/tutorial_table_of_content_facemark.html

Comment: Do they have a sample for it? I want to try it out before I look deeper. I want to check the performance (speed, smoothness and quality), the requirements (hardware, storage-space of SDK...)...

Comment: Added it to the answer

Comment: Seems quite buggy and not accurate. The mask doesn't appear on many cases, and even then might not be in best direction/position. Plus the APK takes 46MB , so this probably means the library takes a lot of space too. Do you know of better free choices ? Also, thank you. I've put +1 for you :)

Answer (score 2):

Google just released their Augmented Faces SDK:

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/unity/augmented-faces/

This will give you a basic mesh over the face so you can place any 'filters' you want